# Try catch as single line if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, try-catch

I need to write a syntax which uses (single line if) statement, but I need to nest it in the sense:

(expression 1)?

(if expression 2 throws `ArgumentException` then `string.empty` else `expression2`):`string.empty`

So Basically I need to figure out a syntax of using try catch inside single line if statement in c# (single line because I need to use it in a linq to sql select statement.)

By single line if statement I mean using ternary operator if statements without having any semicolon.

Comment: Hard to tell, but looks like you are trying to do too much in a single line. Doubtful that there is a legitimate reason to need this.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework assignment?

Comment: `try { shouldIReallyDoThis ? ThenDoINeedTo() : GoodCall() } catch (SeriouslyException e) { DoesThisReallyImproveReadability(); }`

Comment: Also, one does not "Write a syntax".  That is wrong english.  You write code with proper syntax".

Comment: Why does it need to be on a single line?  Technically everything in C# can be on a single line, if that line can contain semi-colons.

Comment: @NominSim That was going to be my next step of breaking it into separate lines,but I though there might be a way. I actually need to to use the code inside a select and so was trying to use a single line if statement.

Comment: @Blachshma No, it is not.

Comment: @EricLeschinski You can write a syntax, that's just not what he's doing.  When, for example, writing the language specs you're defining what the syntax is.

Comment: @Ratan Exceptions are a C# construct, not a SQL construct, and as such such a method couldn't be mapped to SQL.  You almost certainly want to create a stored procedure to do this and just have your C# code call that procedure.

Comment: can We have an example of the kind of Linq to sql statement that you're trying to do, just so we know how your expression fits in?

Comment: var cases = from acc in db.accounts select new { Invoice = ([single-line statement])};

Comment: Assume you have a function template defined as
    
    T SafeFnCall<T>(Func<T> lambda)
    {
        T ret = default(T);
        try
        {
            ret = lambda();
        }
        catch { } // swallow errors, return default
        return ret;
    }

Then you could write your function as

a= flag ? SafeFnCall(() => return expression 1;) : SafeFnCall(() => return expression 2;);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```
(/*expression1*/)? (foo()? string.empty: /*expression2*/):string.empty
```

with foo being:

```
public /*static?*/ bool foo()
{
    try
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    catch(ArgumentException)
    {
        return true
    }
    catch
    {
        return false
    }
    return false;
}
```

As far as embedding Try/Catch into a Linq to Sql statement ... Well let's just say I'd try and rethink my design in that case.

Comment: Given the OP's edits I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question, because it causes you to ask: what criteria should a code block need to be labelled a "single line"?

Obviously, writing 8 lines of code and then removing the line-feed characters doesn't turn it into one line of code.

How about this:

```
    public string Expression2()
    {
        return "One does not write maintainable code this way";
    }

    [Test]
    public void TryCatchAsSingleLine()
    {
        bool expr1 = true;


         // Would you say this is one line?
        string result = expr1 
                            ? (new Func<string>(() => 
                                              { 
                                                 try 
                                                 { 
                                                    return Expression2(); 
                                                 } 
                                                 catch 
                                                 { 
                                                    return string.Empty; 
                                                 } 
                                               }
                                               )
                             )() 
                             : string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this as one-liner:

```
Exception e=null; try { expr1; } catch (Exception ex) {e = ex;} if (e is ArgumentException) { expression2; } else { do whatever or not sure what you want to do with string.empty; }
```

Comment: I need a single line if statement answer. I already know how to do it in more than one line. This is actually needed since I will be suing it in select statement. (Should have made it clear in my original post. I have edited it now.)

Comment: @Ratan First off, you can add a multi-line statement to a `Select` call.  Second, while you *can*, in most situations it's preferable to create a new named method that does most/all of what you would do in such a multi-line anonymous block and just call that method in the anonymous block.

Comment: I don't really see the problem... you can just Select((a)=>{ /* code with try/catch/etc */ }).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a method call or two.

```
class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (ExpressionOne() && ExpressionTwo() != string.Empty) DoSomething();
    }

    static bool ExpressionOne()
    {
        // check something
    }

    static string ExpressionTwo()
    {
        try
        {
            return ThisMayThrowArgumentExceptionOrReturnAString();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is not line oriented, so you can write everything on one line, but the resulting code is not always readable and maintainable.

I would write a separate method for the possibly failing code.

```
public string GetResultSafely()
{
    try {
        // Possibly failing
        return ReadStringFromExternalResource();
    } catch() {
       return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

And then

```
result = expression1 ? GetResultSafely() : GetAnotherResult();
```

---

Note that throwing an exception should not be the standard way of doing things. If possible avoid exceptions.

BAD:

```
try {
    result = x / y;
} catch {
    Console.WriteLine("Division by zero!");
}
```

GOOD:

```
if (y == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Division by zero!");
} else {
    result = x / y;
}
```

But of cause there are situations where exceptions cannot be avoided. Often when accessing external resources.

Comment: Neither of those are good for c#, the scoping bracket convention in c# is on their own line not on the same line as the preceding statement.